building angular library gives path error
i am working with a test angular project where i want to link a local library (existing library) with my existing angular project.
i am trying to build a library that i added in my existing project to use some of its functionality. But when i try to build my lib, it fails with error.
✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

my tsconfig.json is as follows
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    // "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "auth-lib": ["./dist/auth-lib"],
      "@ngfrontend-core*": ["./projects/auth-lib/framework/*/public_api.ts"]
    },
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "tslint-language-service"
      }
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  }
}

